# WPF equivalent to TextRenderer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have used `TextRenderer` to Measure the length of a string and therefore size a control appropriately. Is there an equivalent in WPF or can I simply use `TextRendered.MeasureString`?

Answer (score 21):

Thanks Gishu,

Reading your links I came up with the following both of which do the job for me:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the required height and width of the specified text. Uses FortammedText
    /// </summary>
    public static Size MeasureTextSize(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, FontStretch fontStretch, double fontSize)
    {
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(text,
                                             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                             FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                             new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch),
                                             fontSize,
                                             Brushes.Black);
        return new Size(ft.Width, ft.Height);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the required height and width of the specified text. Uses Glyph's
    /// </summary>
    public static Size MeasureText(string text, FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, FontStretch fontStretch, double fontSize)
    {
        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
        GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;

        if(!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
        {
            return MeasureTextSize(text, fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch, fontSize);
        }

        double totalWidth = 0;
        double height = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
        {
            ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];

            double width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * fontSize;

            double glyphHeight = glyphTypeface.AdvanceHeights[glyphIndex]*fontSize;

            if(glyphHeight > height)
            {
                height = glyphHeight;
            }

            totalWidth += width;
        }

        return new Size(totalWidth, height);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [FormattedText class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext_methods.aspx)

If you need more granular control, then you'd need to descend to the GlyphTypeface type's [AdvanceWidths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.advancewidths.aspx) member. Found a [similar discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a450b0aa-7086-4145-9eff-a779571b6187/) here with a code snippet that looks like it might work.

**Update**: Looks like this may be a duplicate of [Measuring text in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632445/measuring-text-in-wpf) .. OP please confirm.