# TextBlock as big as a capital letter (ignoring font ascender/descender)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking to get a specific behavior on `TextBlock` so that its height only includes the height of the capital letters (from baseline to top minus "ascender height"). Please see the image `Sphinx` from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface) to see what I mean. Also the image below may indicate better what I am after.

[image: Sample]
[image]

I am not specifically looking for a pure XAML solution (probably impossible) so a C# code behind (a converter) is also fine.

This is the XAML used in XamlPad to produce the left A in the image above.

```
<TextBlock Text="A" Background="Aquamarine" FontSize="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: You should use MeasureString, or some similar technique. Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824281/wpf-equivalent-to-textrenderer

Answer (score 5):

u can try to use attribute LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" and a Converter on the LineHeight attributes and a converter on the Height of TextBlock.
This a sample code of converters

```
// Height Converter
public class FontSizeToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static double COEFF = 0.715;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * COEFF;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
// LineHeightConverter
public class FontSizeToLineHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static double COEFF = 0.875;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.Parse(value.ToString()) * COEFF;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The Coefficient used on converters depends on Used Family Fonts (Baseline and LineSpacing):

```
<TextBlock Text="ABC" Background="Aqua" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" 
FontSize="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}" 
FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=listFonts, Path=SelectedItem}" 
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=FontSize, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeToHeightConverter1}}"
LineHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=FontSize, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeToLineHeightConverter}}"/>
```

[image: sample with params Coeff = 0.7]

The best solution is to find how to calculate the Coeff based on parameters Baseline and LineSpacing of the FontFamily.
In this sample (Segeo UI) the Coeff of Height = 0.715 and LineHeight = 0,875 * FontSize.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

If I understand right, there's a few tricks I know for this,

You can `Scale` it with RenderTransform which is usually the most efficient way;

```
<TextBlock Text="Blah">
  <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
   <CompositeTransform ScaleY="3"/>
  </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Or you can embed the `TextBlock` in a `Viewbox` to "zoom" the text to fit the bounds of its container if for example you set hard height values on grid rows like;

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="120"/>
<RowDefinition Height="120"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
      <!-- The textblock and its contents are 
      stretched to fill its parent -->
      <TextBlock Text="Sphinx" />
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
      <!-- The textblock and its contents are 
      stretched to fill its parent -->
      <TextBlock Text="Sphinx2" />
</Viewbox>
```

or you can bind the `FontSize` to a Container element like;

```
<Grid x:Name="MyText" Height="120">
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding ElementName=MyText, Path=Height}" Text="Sphinx" />
</Grid>
```

They might present the effect you're after?

Comment: Hm... not really. I do not see any effect in your first XAML. The second one has an extra ".Value" but still does not do it. Thanks anyway. I have added new image to explain further. I am getting closer to nailing this with a custom converter and multibinding. It is not pretty though. I was looking to get a simple solution.

Comment: Well I tried to do an edit and its not letting me save saying posts cant contain that content? Which is a weird thing with no explanation but I think what you're wanting to do is maybe use GlyphTypeFace to find you lineheight value and set it without your line gap (leading) will look more into later if I have time since now Im curious to, never had a reason to mess with fonts this way before.

Comment: Thanks! I got this working the way I wanted it after all. If nobody comes up with a solution as an exercise, I will post my own answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Yes, please post your results, I'been looking for something similar to this for up/down arrow buttons using the `Marlett` font