# WPF: Reduce/remove empty space above text in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock in which I want to display 2 lines of text in different font sizes, I do not however want all of the wasted space above each line.

My XAML is as follows...

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Center">

    <Run Text="A" FontSize="144" FontWeight="Bold" />

    <LineBreak />

    <Run Text="Service" FontSize="18" />

</TextBlock>
```

And what I end up with is...

[image: An image of what I actually get from my XAML]

Whereas what I want is...

[image: An image of what I am trying to acheive]

Note all the wasted space above the "A", and between the "A" and the "Service" line (I have removed this in the second image - by manipulating the image).

I have tried various combinations of LineHeight, LineStackingStrategy, Margin and Padding property values against not only the TextBlock but also the Paragraph (using a Style) but nothing seems to remove the space.

Can anybody suggest how I should actually achieve this; I am sure it must be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Give Service negative margin doesn't work? eg: `Margin="0 -4 0 0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LineStackingStrategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.linestackingstrategy(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to `BlockLineHeight` and specify a `LineHeight` to get what you want.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Center"
           LineHeight="15.25"
           LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight">
    <Run Text="A" FontSize="144" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Text="Service" FontSize="18" />
</TextBlock>
```

[image: Image with result]

Comment: Thanks for this, I eventually used this technique, but implemented using the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785322/textblock-as-big-as-a-capital-letter-ignoring-font-ascender-descender#15876463).

Comment: In a more general solution, where you don't know the `FontSize` of the `TextBlock` at compile time (but are using a consistent size), just bind `LineHeight` to the same value that you bind `FontSize` to: `<TextBlock LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="{Binding Size}" FontSize="{Binding Size}" />`

Comment: Based on @mrfelis comment, I'm binding LineHeight to FontSize: `LineHeight="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will exactly turn out the way you are searching but you can try.

Put the `TextBlock` into a `DockPanel` or a `StackPanel` as you prefer and then then one of these two in a `ViewBox`.

The `ViewBox` tries to maximize what it contains relatively to the resolution of the wpf window.

The reason to put the `TextBlock` in a `StackPanel` is because the `ViewBox` does not accept more than one child.