# How to vertically center align really big Label in surrounding element

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

How can I vertical center text in a surrounding element?
And/or let the char take up the complete height of the label, without 'ascent' and 'descent'? Aka let Label render the char without 'ascent' and 'descent'.

[image] [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Typography_Line_Terms.svg)

The primitive attempt does not work.
The char is too low.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| The default view | [image] |
| Label with visible background makes the reason obvious the label/font consist of more vertical area than the char | [image] |
| with `VerticalTextAlignment="Center"` on the label only minimal better | [image] |
| tried Clip, but centering is done on the original height (before clip) `<Label.Clip><RectangleGeometry Rect="0,20,100,70" /></Label.Clip>` | [image] |
| Including other chars, makes it obvious, why it behaves like that some chars need the space over or below the "main char" that's just how fonts work. | [image] |

Code:

```
<Grid WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"
    BackgroundColor="HotPink">
    <Ellipse Fill="#1A1A1A"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Label x:Name="numberElm" 
        FontSize="80"
        FontAttributes="Bold" 
        Text="3" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        TextColor="White"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        />
</Grid>
```

Ideally there would be an option to render the number without the extra vertical space.
I didn't find any api or property for that.

The quick and dirty solution i've found is a negative margin like `0,-10,0,0`.

It's kinda similar to this question for wpf: [TextBlock as big as a capital letter (ignoring font ascender/descender)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785322/textblock-as-big-as-a-capital-letter-ignoring-font-ascender-descender)

Comment: `VerticalTextAlignment="Center"`

Comment: @Jason thanks. Included it in the question. Sadly it improves the problem only very slightly. As you can see in the added screenshot.

Comment: I know almost nothing on Xamarin XAML, is there a `line-height` property somewhere?

Comment: @mxmissile sadly no. lineheigt can only be increased, not decreased.

Comment: What if you added a margin-bottom to numberElm?

Comment: @mxmissile that works, it's the nicer equivalent of my workaround `margin-top=-10` I was hoping for a "technical correct" solution which works for any font, parent-container-size. In fancy graphics tools, you usually have exactly this functionality, the char is handled kinda like a vector-graphic and can be centered 100% perfectly.