# Dynamic Fontsize for TextBlock with wrapping

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a TextBlock with a fixed size thats wrapping text. sometimes short sometimes long.

If the text is getting to long it isnt displayed entirely like this

[image]

How can i make the Fontsize flexible to make the text fit the TextBox with static size?

Comment: You could try using a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx), though you may run into problems with the wrapping within the ViewBox.

Comment: Yeah your guess seems to be right it kills the wrapping. Thanks anyway i didnt stumbled on that element yet!

Comment: Are you open to a JavaScript solution?

Comment: You could perhaps try splitting the text into equal-length (in pixels) pieces in a converter and then viewing them using an ItemsControl within the ViewBox. Not the prettiest solution but it might work.

Comment: Since TextRenderer can do the equivalent for WinForms, this post might help you get an alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824281/wpf-equivalent-to-textrenderer

Comment: I used AdaptiveTrigger-functionality to implement this for my simple scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution is the following:

Set the fontsize to a value, than which you don't want any bigger.
The ActualHeight of the TextBlock changes, when you change the font size or when the content is changed. I built the solution based upon this.
You should create an event handler for the SizeChanged event and write the following code to it.

```
private void MyTextBlock_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double desiredHeight = 80; // Here you'll write the height you want the text to use

    if (this.MyTextBlock.ActualHeight > desiredHeight)
    {
        // You want to know, how many times bigger the actual height is, than what you want to have.
        // The reason for Math.Sqrt() is explained below in the text.
        double fontsizeMultiplier = Math.Sqrt(desiredHeight / this.MyTextBlock.ActualHeight);

        // Math.Floor() can be omitted in the next line if you don't want a very tall and narrow TextBox.
        this.MyTextBlock.FontSize = Math.Floor(this.MyTextBlock.FontSize * fontsizeMultiplier);
    }

    this.MyTextBlock.Height = desiredHeight; // ActualHeight will be changed if the text is too big, after the text was resized, but in the end you want the box to be as big as the desiredHeight.
}
```

The reason why I used the Math.Sqrt() is that if you set the font size to half as big as before, then the area that the font will use, will be one quarter the size, then before (because it became half as wide and half as tall as before). And you obviously want to keep the width of the TextBox and only change the height of it.

If you were lucky, the font size will be appropriate after this method gets executed once. However, depending on the text that gets re-wrapped after the font size change, you might be so "unlucky", that the text will be one line longer than you would want it to be.
Luckily the event handler will be called again (because you changed the font size) and the resizing will be done again if it is still too big.

I tried it, it was fast and the results looked good.
However, I can imagine, that in a really unlucky choice of text and height, the correct font size would be reached after several iterations. This is why I used Math.Floor(). All in all, it doesn't matter much if the font size is in the end 12.34 or 12 and this way I wouldn't be concerned about an "unlucky" text, which will take too long to render.
But I think Math.Floor() can be omitted if you don't want to have a really tall text box (like 2000 pixels) with a lot of text.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. Note; I realise this does not apply in the OP's case but in a Windows 10 App that you can resize in a window on the desktop, this will cause the text to shrink but not grow larger again.

Comment: @tagy22 remove the if statement and it'll resize in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution including an option to set maxheight / maxwidth and and it is calculated straight on render:

```
public class TextBlockAutoShrink : TextBlock
    {
        private double _defaultMargin = 6;
        private Typeface _typeface;

        static TextBlockAutoShrink()
        {
            TextBlock.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlockAutoShrink), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChanged)));
        }

        public TextBlockAutoShrink() : base() 
        {
            _typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, this.FontStretch, this.FontFamily);
            base.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(TextBlockAutoShrink_DataContextChanged);
        }

        private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var t = sender as TextBlockAutoShrink;
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.FitSize();
            }
        }

        void TextBlockAutoShrink_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FitSize();
        }

        protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
        {
            FitSize();

            base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        }


        private void FitSize()
        {
            FrameworkElement parent = this.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                var targetWidthSize = this.FontSize;
                var targetHeightSize = this.FontSize;

                var maxWidth = double.IsInfinity(this.MaxWidth) ? parent.ActualWidth : this.MaxWidth;
                var maxHeight = double.IsInfinity(this.MaxHeight) ? parent.ActualHeight : this.MaxHeight;

                if (this.ActualWidth > maxWidth)
                {
                    targetWidthSize = (double)(this.FontSize * (maxWidth / (this.ActualWidth + _defaultMargin)));
                }

                if (this.ActualHeight > maxHeight)
                {
                    var ratio = maxHeight / (this.ActualHeight);

                    // Normalize due to Height miscalculation. We do it step by step repeatedly until the requested height is reached. Once the fontsize is changed, this event is re-raised
                    // And the ActualHeight is lowered a bit more until it doesnt enter the enclosing If block.
                    ratio = (1 - ratio > 0.04) ? Math.Sqrt(ratio) : ratio;

                    targetHeightSize = (double)(this.FontSize *  ratio);
                }

                this.FontSize = Math.Min(targetWidthSize, targetHeightSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `_typeface` isn't used in your sample.