# Pick font size to fit string to width

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

There is method `MeasureString` in `Graphics` class, which helps user to find out, what size string has for specified font. But what if I want to know opposite - pick proper font size to fit text to width?

Actual use-case: I have multiple `TextBlock`s, which should have same font size. I'd like to reduce size of text of all blocks, if width of any `TextBlock` content exceeds certain value (for example, width of `TextBlock` and some margin). For now, I'm using `MeasureString`, to calculate some multiplier, which affects font size, but it seems, that it works not as I wanted it to - it leaves way too big gaps.

For example, I have limit of width 75 px, default font size 13, and string with width 125 px. (75/125) * 13 gives me 7.8 font size, which causes string to have 52 px in width (way much smaller than 75).

So, any good ways to do this?

Code
In ViewModel:

```
private int _defaultFontSize = 13;
private int _maxStringSize = 75;
private string _text = "MoreMoreMore"; //test text, which exceeds 75 px

public double NameFontSize
{
    get
    {
        var font = new Font("Segoe UI Light", _defaultNameFontSize);
        double size;
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
        {
            size = graphics.MeasureString(_text, font);
        }

        return Math.Min(1, _maxStringSize/size) * _defaultFontSize;
    }
}

public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
}
```

In XAML

```
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Text}" FontSize = "{Binding NameFontSize}"/>
```

Comment: Can you show related code? The idea with scaling is correct approach (this is what TTF meant for).

Comment: @Sinatr Added example code (it's doing literally what I've described). Problem is, that I seek method, which will give in result not ~50 px width, but more to 70 px. It seems, that font scaling is not very precise.

Comment: See [measuring text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/632445/1997232) in wpf. Maybe you are not measuring *correct* size with your method. I am not sure if `MeasureString` (gdi+) can be used to calculate wpf `FontSize`.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it already. Now I'm working on much nastier method to get string width, since WPF doesn't allow to directly push readonly properties to VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're measuring with different font size units.

The [`System.Drawing.Font` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8882dhsk(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an em-size in points, which are `1/72` of an inch

> *emSize*: ... The em-size, in points, of the new font.

while [`TextBlock.FontSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(v=vs.100).aspx) is given in WPF units, which are `1/96` inch:

> ... An unqualified value is measured in device independent pixels. ...

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. I had to apply different approach - use ActualWidth instead of one found by MeasureString. Which led me to different problem - getting read-only properties of controls in view-model (MVVM). Anyway, solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting the TextBlock inside a ViewBox and let that take care of the scaling?

```
<Viewbox Width="75">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Any way to share this scale with another TextBlocks?

Comment: @lentinant not that I know of.