# Get character's height without padding from FormattedText

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the exact height of characters such as [.] [,] [j] [g] [a] [l].

I tried this

```
FormattedText formattedText = getText(".");
var height1 = formattedText.Height; //Extra space will be included
var height2 = formattedText.Baseline; //Characters such as [j] are cut off.
```

Comment: `FormattedText` is a control, to [measure text in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/632445/1997232) I expect you will need something else, some low level function used to print/draw text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `formattedText` to a `geometry` object and thus get the actual `height` and `width` dimensions.

```
Point p_text = new Point(0, 0);
Geometry _pathGeometry;
            _pathGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(p_text);
Path path = new Path();
            path.Data = _pathGeometry;
            double height = path.Height;
            double width = path.Width;
```

Try to do it.